# How do you update pushed route when the widget that pushed it updates?

Tags: flutter, dart

So right now I have this structure:

```
StreamBuilder<List> -> WidgetA -> widgetPushedByWidgetA
```

I push the widget like this:

```dart
() => Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute<Widget>(
            builder: (_) => WidgetPushedByA(list),
        ),
      ),
```

The problem is that when the stream updates the list within `WidgetA`, the Widget pushed by A isn't updated with the new list. Is there some way to do this? This is mostly irrelavent but the stream is coming from firebase.

Comment: can you provide more information?

Comment: Maybe you could send the stream itself because the `list` variable that you are sending via the constructor is immutable in that class (final / const). So any change in the list in previous screen won't be reflected in the current visible screen.

Comment: @DarShan Oh wow awesome I didn't think of that! I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: why not use name routing with parameter passing?

Comment: you can listen to the stream and use ValueListenableBuilder with bool value to update the data in the pushed route